# VBox will not verify signatures for apt

Tags: virtualbox, apt, public-key, apt-get

I cannot run sudo apt-get update without an error relating to virtualbox and its public key.

I have tried to purge virtualbox, on numerous occasions I have deleted and re-downloaded the keys. I have tried to delete the virtualbox apt repository. However, the same errors persist:

Err:11 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian quantal InRelease
The following signatures were invalid: 7B0FAB3A13B907435925D9C954422A4B98AB5139
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian quantal InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 7B0FAB3A13B907435925D9C954422A4B98AB5139
E: The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian quantal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I would like sudo apt-get update to work again. Please can anyone help out?

Comment: Hi just wanted to ask if you can update your post and tags to include a host and guest operating system and the release version of VBox

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to programming